# Detecting .mat version using python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, hdf5

I am aware of the two alternatives to read .mat files using python. For .mat files prior to the 7.3 version the function scipy.io.loadmat works perfectly. For .mat files from the 7.3 version, you need to use a HDF5 reader like h5py.

My question is; is there a way to find, for a given file, its version of .mat within python? This way I can create a function that reads any .mat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EAFP (it is easier to ask forgiveness than permission)

[scipy.loadmat](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/93bf1a6a494fef15b383831529543c7c17635f24/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py#L71) 
does check the version and raises an error if it is not supported.

```
try:

    import scipy.io as sio
    test = sio.loadmat('test.mat')

except NotImplementedError:

    import h5py
    with h5py.File('test.mat', 'r') as hf:
        data = hf['name-of-dataset'][:]

except:
    ValueError('could not read at all...')
```

If you want to do the checking yourself, you can use `get_matfile_version()` in [scipy.io.matlab.miobase.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/93bf1a6a494fef15b383831529543c7c17635f24/scipy/io/matlab/miobase.py#L187). Usage as in the first link.

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I needed. I thought about using the try except example but I thought it would be kind of bad practice if a checking function existed already. Is this the case?

Comment: I would not say it is bad practice. You can also the checking function and some `if` conditions to really check for the version number. It might be even clearer to use `h5py` just if the version in `get_matfile_version()` is `2`. Who knows what else might raise a `NotImplementedError` :) It just depends on if you want to use `get_matfile_version()` and sneak preview the file.